# Are country- and form-specific questions allowed?

Tags: discussion

I would like to ask a very specific question for a specific form from a specific country since the competent Embassy is not getting back to me with the information I need. Is this allowed or is it too specific? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, e.g. [What is the last point where one can throw away fruits if one has indicated “not bringing any fruit” on the US customs form when flying to the US?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/149561/1810)

Comment: Thank you but I decided to post it on Expatriates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the form is about travel for the short term, like a visit visa, it belongs on our site and is welcome.

If it is about a long term visa, it belongs on our sister site [Expatriates](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/).

When unsure, just post it and I will get it to the right place for you if it needs moving.